# Choose axis for assignment into NumPy array programmatically

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3D numpy array.

I can modify arbitrary element using simple indexing

```
D[:,:,0]=myval
D[:,:10,1]=list(range(10))
```

Sometimes I need to change element(s) at a given index and it is not predetermined at which axis the index refers.
I would like to catch the two following cases with a change in variable

```
D[:,:10,1]=list(range(10)) ->axis 1
D[:10,:,1]=list(range(10)) ->axis 0
```

Something like:

```
f(D,axis=0/1,index=1,newval)
```

Comment: Look at `np.take`.  Or construct an indexing `tuple`

Comment: @hpaulj `np.take` wouldn't help with assignment, would it?

Answer (score 3):

I'd use an indexing tuple with slice objects prepared by the helper object [`np.s_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html). If `axis` is 0 or 1, the following has the effect of assigning `list(range(10))` to either `D[:10, :, 1]` or `D[:, :10, 1]`.

```
idx = [np.s_[:], np.s_[:], 1] 
idx[axis] = np.s_[:10]
D[tuple(idx)] = list(range(10))
```